# How do I insert element reference in an xpath string?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests

Given a UI element reference, how do I "append" a string to it so that I can find its next sibling element of type `XCUIElementTypeStaticText`?

The framework I am using contains a `driver_helper.py` file.

Within that file are the `find_element` & `find_elements` methods defined as:

```
def find_element(self, locator: tuple) -> WebElement:
return self.driver.find_element(*locator)
def find_elements(self, locator: tuple) -> list[WebElement]:
return self.driver.find_elements(*locator)
```

There is also a `selector_const.py` file containing declarations for the various types of selectors. The one I am using specifically for this question is:

`BY_XPATH = MobileBy.XPATH`

In the screen/page object file I am working on, I define a tuple
`self.CHECKBOXES = (sc.BY_XPATH, '//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Square"]')`

which I then use to create this variable:
`checkboxes = self.driver_helper.find_elements(self.CHECKBOXES)`

I want to find a sibling element to one of the checkboxes, but this snippet of code:

```
checkboxes = self.driver_helper.find_elements(self.CHECKBOXES)
sibling = (
            sc.BY_XPATH,
            f'{checkboxes[0]}/following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeStaticText',
        )
test = self.driver_helper.find_element(sibling)
print("checkbox 0 sibling element text: " + str(test))
```

fails with `NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.` 
I have included a screenshot of the domain of the screen to show that the checkboxes do exist and that there is an `XCUIElementTypeStaticText` right next to it

Domain of iOS app screen:

```
<XCUIElementTypeButton type="XCUIElementTypeButton" name="Square" label="Square" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="15" y="428" width="20" height="21" index="22"/>
<XCUIElementTypeStaticText type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" value="checkbox 1 text" name="checkbox 1 text" label="checkbox 1 text" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="43" y="428" width="308" height="18" index="23"/>
<XCUIElementTypeButton type="XCUIElementTypeButton" name="Square" label="Square" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="15" y="478" width="20" height="21" index="24"/>
<XCUIElementTypeStaticText type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" value="checkbox 2 text" name="checkbox 2 text" label="checkbox 2 text" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="43" y="478" width="260" height="35" index="25"/>
<XCUIElementTypeButton type="XCUIElementTypeButton" name="Square" label="Square" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="15" y="542" width="20" height="21" index="26"/>
<XCUIElementTypeStaticText type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" value="checkbox 3 text" name="checkbox 3 text" label="checkbox 3 text" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="43" y="542" width="333" height="86" index="27"/>
<XCUIElementTypeButton type="XCUIElementTypeButton" name="Square" label="Square" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="15" y="657" width="20" height="21" index="28"/>
<XCUIElementTypeStaticText type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" value="checkbox 4 text" name="checkbox 4 text" label="checkbox 4 text" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="43" y="657" width="320" height="52" index="29"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add methods in the `driver_helper.py`, you can implement there a method using the solution provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74248035/12023661)
But if you can not do that, you need to change the code of your `sibling` variable. Now you are trying to put an element into XPATH and this can not work as you put an object into a string.
So, the workaround is to put there the XPATH string which you use to find the parent element.
As you get all the checkboxes into a list, you can iterate through the them and get the siblings like this:

```
for i in range(len(checkboxes)):
    sibling = (sc.BY_XPATH, f'(//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Square"])[{i+1}]/following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeStaticText')
    test = self.driver_helper.find_element(sibling)
    print(f"checkbox {i+1} sibling element text: {test.text}")
```

Comment: Same results. I tried changing both [{i+1}] & [{i}] as the passed in index, and both failed. 

==============
        

for i in range(len(checkboxes)):
            sibling = (sc.BY_XPATH, f'(//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Square"])[{i+1}]/XCUIElementTypeStaticText')
            test = self.driver_helper.find_element(sibling)
            print(f"checkbox {i+1} sibling element text: {test.text}")

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot about an important part of the code: `following-sibling::`. Now I've edited the code. Can you try it once more?

Comment: This worked. Ty very much! I noticed you had missed that small snippet earlier (the following-sibling:: part), but for whatever reason, when I tried adding it myself it was still failing. That being said, I copy-pasted your newly edited answer and that was successful. I will award you the bounty as soon as I am able. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Store all the XPath in a variable:

```
main_element = "//*[@id="submenu1"]/a[2]"

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, main_element)


siblingElement = main_element + "/following-sibling::td"

element2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, siblingElement)
```

Answer (score 1):

You **can not** insert `WebElement` object / reference in XPath string because Xpath expression should be **string** as you mentioned yourself.
What you do can is to locate the other element based on the existing element.
For example, if you want to find the `/following-sibling::td` based on existing element you can do it as following:

```py
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="submenu1"]/a[2]')
siblingElement = element.find_element(By.XPATH, './following-sibling::td')
```

1. In the second line I'm applying `find_element` method on `element` object, not on `driver` object.
2. The XPath expression is staring with a dot `.` there to notify that this relative XPath is related to the current node.
3. `find_element(By.XPATH,` is used now while `find_element_by_xpath` is deprecated.
   **UPD**
   In case you want to find sibling elements of a list of elements you can do something like this:

```py
base_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'the_xpath_locator')
for element in base_elements:
    siblingElement = element.find_element(By.XPATH, './following-sibling::td')
```

Comment: What if I use findelements call to store an array of references in the variable ?

Comment: In that case you will need to iterate over the list of objects while applying the approach I mentioned on each element in the list

Comment: I tried passing in a hard-coded value for testing purposes, but am still not finding the element. I added more specific information to the question for more context.

Comment: In your updated question is not what I meant. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately that did not work either.

Comment: Please share XML / HTML of that screen (I understand it's mobile app) so we can make some basic debugging.

Comment: Ok, added the XML/HTML of the screen